# Error in pushing code to Heroku

Tags: git, heroku

While pushing my code to Heroku, I am getting these error

Can you anybody please advice what am I missing here, is this the versioning issue or something else ?

```
git push heroku master

-----> Heroku receiving push
-----> Ruby/Rails app detected
-----> Detected Rails is not set to serve static_assets
       Installing rails3_serve_static_assets... done
-----> Configure Rails 3 to disable x-sendfile
       Installing rails3_disable_x_sendfile... done
-----> Configure Rails to log to stdout
       Installing rails_log_stdout... done
-----> Gemfile detected, running Bundler version 1.0.7
       Unresolved dependencies detected; Installing...
       Using --without development:test
       Fetching source index for http://rubygems.org/
       Could not find multi_json-1.3.3 in any of the sources
       FAILED: http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/bundler
 !     Heroku push rejected, failed to install gems via Bundler
```

Comment: `multi_json` version 1.3.3 doesn't seem to exist in the default gem repositories. Just upgrade to 1.3.4 if possible and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue too. Added the code below as a line in the Gemfile and pushed it to Heroku and it worked.

```
gem 'multi_json', '1.3.4'
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

multi_json-1.3.3 has been yanked in the meantime. That's why it can't be found on the rubygems server. To make it work:

1. remove version from the Gemfile (or set it to 1.3.4)
2. run 'bundle update multi_json`
3. commit Gemfile and Gemfile.lock to the repository
4. push it to heroku

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

When I got this error I needed to remove the Gemfile.lock

Answer (score 0):

Removed the Gemfile.lock

Reset the gemfile version to 1.3.4

ran the bundle

committed gemfile and gemfile repository

pushed to heroku

Push was successful